How to download a website for offline viewing and sharing
I have made a website for a client on drag and drop builder called SHOWIT, now I want to save the version I created for my portfolio. A few reasons, the site could go disabled, the design could change in future, etc. How do I save the website for my portfolio that it is presentable, should I make a figma file and do linking prototype? I tried saving as HTML but it only opens locally, is there a way to host the offline version for public viewing?
I TRIED HHTRACK SAVED AS HTML BUT I NEED WEBSITE FOR PUBLIC VIEWING

Ftp into the public folder and download it. Public viewing offline? Your site needs to be online somewhere to be reachable unless you make a memory stick or something

Hi, could your elaborate more on memory stick? I mean I have the version downloaded with me in my computer, and share it with people to view that version I downloaded

To share it, you can install a web server on your computer and give access to that, OR load the folder onto a memory stick and give that to the people, assuming relative navigation and not need for a database

I will look into it, thanks!
